# The correct way to fetch a lot of data in PHP5 object oriented

Tags: php, sql, oop

Fortunately, I know how to fetch data from the database, That's not a problem. 
For my object oriented application I would have a table with users / persons. 
I also have a `person` class.

**The case:**
I would like to show to the end user a list with all the persons. What is the correct way to show do this?

1. using `mysql_fetch_object()` in this case php will create it's own type
   of object, not my own type of `person`
2. Fetching all the rows from the db and then create an object of each?

Or is there an other better way to do it?

Can you also please show some (pseudo) code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_object) function takes a second parameter, which is the class name to use:

```
$myPerson = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'person');
```

Comment: Don't forget to throw away references to objects after writing them out, else you'll exhaust your available memory if you have too many of them around.

Answer (score 3):

- option 1: use ORM (Propeler, Doctrine)
- option 2: create class People ("Persons"), which will load it's data using `mysql_fetch_*`, then create array of Person objects. Have it implement `IteratorAggregate` with `getIterator` returning `ArrayIterator(personArray)`

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I have so fare created the iterator but don't really know how to use it.

Comment: if you have object People which implements IteratorAggregate, you can use it with: foreach (people as person) { doSomethingWith(person) }

Comment: Ok, I will try to work it out else I will elaborate on it in a different topic. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), [`$pdoStatement->fetchObject($type)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) fetches a single row as instance of `$type` Class

To fetch all objects as instance of `$type` Class, use  [`$pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $type)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But we don't use the pdo class. We made our own